# Batch Request in office365 php gives Bad Request

Tags: php, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am using Office365 To Sync Email in PHP. The Office 365 REST API supports batch requests. I have tried to use this to retrieve emails using the Office 365 REST API, but so far I receive a "BadRequest." reply. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the sample code

```
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch';

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$accessToken,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$msgid1 = "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC1kMjFjLWUyMTUtMDACLTAPwAAAHzY91EAAAA=";
$msgid2 = "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC1kMjFjLWUyMTUtDACLTvpPwAAAHzY91AAAAA=";
$msgid3 = "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC1kMjFjLWUyMTRRRBGUtMDACLAAHzY908AAAA=";

$params = array(
    'requests' => array(
        array( 
            "id" => "1",
            "method" => "GET",
            "url" => "/me/messages/$msgid1/attachments"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => "2",
            "method" => "GET",
            "url" => "/me/messages/$msgid2/attachments"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => "3",
            "method" => "GET",
            "url" => "/me/messages/$msgid3/attachments"
        )
    )
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

In Response i receive **Invalid batch payload format** message.

Answer (score 1):

Oh.. There is error in my code.

Do

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));

insted of 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);